# Upgrading Perl in Ubuntu

Tags: perl, ubuntu

Since May 14th the current version of Perl is 5.14. In Ubuntu repository the current version of Perl is 5.10 which is no longer supported. So Im trying to manually upgrading Perl.
What is the recommended way to upgrade perl 5.10 to perl 5.14 in Ubuntu?
I found the perlbrew tool, but it seems to install just in the users home.

Comment: This is not really programming related. You should ask on http://askubuntu.com

Comment: [perlbrew](http://search.cpan.org/~gugod/App-perlbrew-0.28/lib/App/perlbrew.pm)

Comment: Yes it installs in the users home. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Perlbrew docs](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3aperlbrew) says that you can change your `$HOME` dir to something else:

> The directory `~/perl5/perlbrew` will contain all install perl
>   executables, libraries, documentations, lib, site_libs. If you need to
>   install `perlbrew`, and the perls it brews, into somewhere else because,
>   say, your HOME has limited quota, you can do that by setting a
>   `PERLBREW_ROOT` environment variable before running the installer:
>
> ```
> export PERLBREW_ROOT=/opt/perlbrew curl -L
> http://xrl.us/perlbrewinstall | bash
> ```

Answer (score 2):

download, configure, compile ....